# Nginx settings for webservics with SSL (https)

Tags: django, web-services, ssl, nginx, config

Nginx newbie here! I have the following dummy code:

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
<p id="demo_id"></p>

<script>

function myFunction() 
{
    var loc = window.location;
    var wsStart = 'ws://';
    if (loc.protocol == 'https:') 
    {
        wsStart = 'wss://'
    }      

    var port =":8080" <!-- 
    var endpoint = wsStart + loc.host + port+'/personal/my_random_number/';

socket = new WebSocket(endpoint);

socket.onmessage = function(e) 
{
    document.getElementById("demo_id").innerHTML = e.data;
}

socket.onopen = function() 
{
    socket.send("hello world #");
} 

</script>
```

and nginx settings like this (ssl commented out):

```
server {
listen 80;
#listen 443 ssl;
server_name 157.200.0.100;

 #ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com-0002/fullchain.pem;
 #ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com-0002/privkey.pem;


# serve static files
location /static/ {
alias /www/static_3/;
}

# serve media files
location /media/ {
alias /www/media_3/;
}

location / {
proxy_pass http://$server_name:8080;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
}
}

#server {
#        listen 80;
#        server_name 157.200.0.100;
#        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
#}
```

while the web service works perfectly on http (non secure) I couldn't figure how to allow wss to work with ssl (I commented out the SSL settings, when I use the SSL setting, the site works ok but not the WSS).

**Question:** how to 'upgrade' my nginx settings where the WS can work with SSL?

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> var port =":8080" <!-- 
> var endpoint = wsStart + loc.host + port+'/personal/my_random_number/';
> ```

Your `ws://...` uses port 8080 which does not seem to be handled by nginx at all - at least the nginx config you provide shows only port 80 and (commented out) 443. This means there is likely some (unknown) standalone server (maybe nodejs?) which provides only support for plain `ws://`.

Thus in order to provide `wss://` support you must  add this support to your unknown websocket server. And if you want to support both `ws://` and `wss://` these likely have to be on different ports - only few servers allow plain HTTP (or `ws://`) and HTTPS (or `wss://`) to share the same port.

Another often used option is to use nginx as a reverse proxy for websockets. In this case the standard ports are used (i.e. no longer 8080) and nginx routes the request to the inner `ws://` server. This way `wss://` will automatically be translated to a local `ws://` request and no changes on the local websocket server need to be done. See [NGINX as a WebSocket Proxy](https://www.nginx.com/blog/websocket-nginx/) for more details on this.

Comment: thanks for elaborating. I did mention port 8080 in the nginx un location (proxy_pass http://$server_name:8080;) unless I missed something.